# wp get category name in get_posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

The following code will print an array with all posts with custom field 'job_location' as 'US'. Its works well and shows post title, description and all data relate to each post.

My requirement is, I want to get the category name of each post. I dont want to accomplish this by looping the posts and get the category details of each posts, since that will need extra db access. So Is there any way to get the category details in 'get_posts' function itself?

```
$meta_query =array('key' => 'job_location','value' => 'US');

$post_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish','suppress_filters' => true, 'meta_query' => $meta_query
);
$posts_list = get_posts( $post_args );

var_dump($posts_list);
```

Comment: Is the desired result to have a list of posts and another separate list of all the categories used by the that list of posts?

Comment: No, I want category id and category name for each posts.

Comment: Is the answer I provided what you're looking forward? If it's not then please provide more info on what you're trying to accomplish and the code you have thus far.

Comment: You can't. BTW, `get_the_category` and `get_the_terms` does not query the database from a normal query, so you are not making any extra db calls, even if you call those two functions a thousand times. You should move this [wordpress.se] and I will fully explain this if nobody else does it before me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) to retrieve a list of categories for a post. For example if `$post` contains a post object then `$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID )` will return an "*Array of objects, one for each category assigned to the post*".